# What does "the dark-blonde fringe that framed her unruly eyes" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, swimming-in-the-dark, tomasz-jedrowski

I would like to know what "the dark-blonde
fringe that framed her unruly eyes" means in the following sentences:

> I turned back to Karolina. She was smoking, her wide lips painted
> coral-red and leaving a mark on the mouth of the cigarette. I can’t
> remember ever having seen her without that lipstick, or without **the
> dark-blonde fringe that framed her unruly eyes**.

- [Tomasz Jedrowski, *Swimming in the Dark*, Chapter 2](https://www.booker6.com/book/202006/842_6.html)

In this novel which is set in the 1980's in Poland under the socialist regime, where homosexuality was socially unacceptable, the protagonist Ludwik (a university graduate) left Poland in 1981 to live in the United States of America. And he remembers what it was like back then in Poland, where he went to the agricultural camp (which was mandatory for college graduation). On the way to the camp, Ludwik turned to his best friend Karolina, who was sitting next to him on the bus.

In this part, I wonder what "framed" here means especially.
Does it mean that her dark-blonde fringe accentuated her unruly eyes, perhaps...?

I am an English learner from South Korea, so thank you for your patience in advance as I may not know obvious things. I would very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particularly context specific about this. If you look up the verb 'frame' in online dictionaries you can readily find examples such as this from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frame):

> to form an edge to something in an attractive way:
>
> *Her new hairstyle frames her face in a much more flattering way*.

Comment: It would be better if you also explained what 'fringe' means.

Comment: There is nothing in the question to indicate that the meaning of  'fringe' is a mystery, surely?

Comment: No there isn't. I think it might make the answer complete

Comment: @CinCout That seems completely random, can you explain why you think 'fringe' specifically needs glossing when the querent doesn't appear to have a difficulty with it?

Comment: In the highlighted phrase "the dark-blonde fringe that framed her unruly eyes", the verb framed is acting on the fringe, so I thought explaining it might make the answer sound more complete. That could be just me, and if it is so, please ignore.

Comment: @CinCout The OPs question 'Does it mean that her dark-blonde fringe accentuated her unruly eyes, perhaps...?' suggests to me that they perfectly understand the relationship of the fringe to the eyes. So I'm just extremely confused as to where you are coming from with this. If you feel that an answer which addresses that would be better, please crack on and write one